# How to deal with unstable library changes

Tags: android, android-library

I am using some libraries in my android project, which currently are stable. But in further version, if the library developers made some mistakes or removed the earlier functionality, then how can I make my app handle this change and avoid breaking? I am looking for some such strategies to make my app more robust and consistent even if the library functionality changes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you will update version of library, it will not be changed, but library developers later may remove version you used from support and use.
Also, you can import library by yourself.
Moreover, it is better to develop functions by yourself, if you are not sure about library future.